# Resizing images in django with PILLOW does not work

Tags: python, django-models, python-imaging-library

I want to scale every Image I upload to server into 500x500, I found this piece of code in one of my previous projects and it clearly does not work. I tried `img = Image.open(self.image)` and it didn't even open an image, but in this case `img = Image.open(self.image.path)` it says it can't open `.../media/example.jpg`, it's because I store product thumbnails at `.../media/images/example.jpg`. I have no idea how to fix it. This is my code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from PIL import Image

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2500)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
    price = models.IntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(f"{self.name}")

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 500 or img.width > 500:
            output_size = (500, 500)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

        super(Product, self).save()
```

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. Maybe it never execute this code. or it has wrong values and generate some error. We can't run this code so you have to debug it on your own.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you have file in `.../media/images` instead of `.../media` then simply replace text `media` with `media/images` in path.  ie. `self.image.path.replace("media", "media/images")`